# Add Text to Compose.jl Shapes

Tags: julia

I would like to overlay text on shapes from Compose.jl. For example, let's say i want to overlay a label on the center of this shape:

```
using Compose

compose(
context(), fill(LCHab(78, 84, 29)),
(context(0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2), rectangle(), fill("green")),
(context(0.0, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2), rectangle(), fill(LCHab(68, 74, 192))))
```

How can I overlay text onto these objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet of code that overlays text on some shapes:

```
compose(
context(), fill("black"),
(context(0.2, 0.5), text(0.2, 0.1,"eeee", Compose.hcenter, Compose.vcenter)),
(context(0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2), rectangle(), fill("green")),
(context(0.0, 0.6), text(0.25, 0.1, "aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccc", Compose.hcenter, Compose.vcenter)),
(context(0.0, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2), rectangle(), fill("red"))
)
```

The code produces the following output:

[image: text superimposed on figures]

The two first arguments to `text()` are the position of the text in relation to the current context.

`Compose.hcenter` and `Compose.vcenter` are optional, they set the horizontal and vertical alignment of the text. The options are for alignment are:

- `vleft`
- `vcenter`
- `vright`
- `htop`
- `hcenter`
- `hbottom`

---

Unfortunately I have not found documentation for the `text()` function to link to, only its definition, which can be found [here](https://github.com/dcjones/Compose.jl/blob/master/src/form.jl#L360) on github.

Comment: `LCHab()` caused error for me, so I've replaced it with string based colors.